# How to adjust Ives Rota Closer

Tags: doors, closer

The door to our garage has an Ives Rota Closer.  In the past the door has always swung shut on its own, however today our daughter was pulling the door open (a bit too far I think) and now it suddenly seems to have lost its "pull" and the door no longer closes on its own.

There is no model number or other information on the closer except for the words "To adjust / Push up & turn" and an arrow pointing down to a short cylinder of some sort which comes out of the bottom and which is slotted for a negative screwdriver. But when I barely press up on it the cylinder goes all the way inside and only slowly comes out again.  There appears to be some kind of lubricant on it as well.  I have tried turning the cylinder with a screwdriver with and without pushing the cylinder up into the barrel but there is almost no resistance to turning and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I haven't been able to find any kind of manual for this device, but obviously *wants* to be adjusted, so what am I doing wrong in trying?

Here is a picture of the device:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds seem excellent that it was  coiled spring closer, and the spring (having been overstressed by wide opening, and/or simply from old age) is now snapped, so "adjusting it" won't happen. Replace, with any suitable door closer (ie, it need not be this particular type, if it's hard to find, which seems likely)

Here's some info, though it does not directly confirm or deny my suspicions: http://www.epivots.com/mpowr-mp-800.aspx

Comment: good to know, thanks!  i'll leave the question open a bit before I accept in case there are any additional answers.

Comment: I'm guessing - let it stew for a good while (a month or more, if that's what it takes) in case someone that actually owns one of these comes along. I'm not exactly in need of points ;-)

Comment: incidentally, that link is to a "light duty" door closer for doors up to 35 pounds.  All my searches turn up empty, does anybody still make heavy duty closers?  This is a solid wood door, much heavier than a mere 35 pounds.

Comment: They are certainly made - more in "commercial" than "residential" market/channels. though the internet can generally blend those. Shape would generally be different than this one.